# ImportError: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct - Python 3.4, Kivy 1.10, Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, kivy, raspberry-pi3

I have been trying to get Kivy to work on my raspberry pi with Python 3.4, but it is proving very difficult. I followed Kivy's guide to installing it on the RPi from https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-rpi.html.

I used the following code just to see if I can import a few different kivy libraries.

```
import kivy #Works just fine
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
```

None of the from/imports work using Python 3.4. I get the following error when trying to run on Python 3.4 if I just try importing kivy.animation

```
ImportError: /home/pi/kivy/kivy/_event.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

I get the following similar error when trying to import just kivy.app or kivy.uix.button

```
ImportError: /home/pi/kivy/kivy/_clock.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

I had been using TKinter for my GUI prior to this with all of my development being in Python 3.4. Kivy looks to provide a little bit more professional ui tools which is why I would like to switch over. However, Kivy doesn't seem to want to work with Python 3.4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I need to provide anything else, please let me know.

wayneStock

Comment: I found in following [kivy issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5151) on github.

Comment: I have done a fresh reinstall of both cython and kivy. It appears the problem went away when federico reinstalled using sudo pip install git+https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git@master, however it prompts for an username and pw. Not sure if I am missing something, but I cannot find that information